# how to generate natural spline in matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, numerical-methods, spline, cubic-spline

I noticed that there are only not-a-knot and clamped spline in Matlab, which is assembled in the function spline. Can we change the original code in matlab a little bit so it can perform (or only perform) natural spline? I felt like it is a easy task since we need only to change the extra two degrees of freedom of parameters, such that it is satisfied to have zero second derivatives at the end points. But staring at the code of spline I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you right click on a function in the editor, the menu will offer you to open the script file.

Comment: I meant how can we change the original code and make a new matlab function...I already got the function that matlab has for spline.